# Calculate $\lim_{\sigma\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{d_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Calculate 
>   $$\lim_{\sigma\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{d_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx$$
>   where 
>   $$d_1 = \frac{\ln \left( \frac{S}{K} \right) + (r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}.$$
>   Note that all $S,K,r,\tau$ are positive constants.

It seems that answer is $\frac{1}{2}.$
But I have no idea how to evaluate it.

Comment: It seems $d_1\to\infty$.

Comment: The lower limit of the integral is really $\infty$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry. Lower limit should be $-\infty$. Edited.

Comment: OK, then it looks like the limit should just be $(1/\sqrt{2\pi})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}$ (you don't really want two minus signs in that exponent, do you?) and that's just the standard normal distribution integral, which I imagine you recognize.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So the answer is $1$?

Comment: Why do you think that the answer seems to be $\frac12$?

Comment: @robjohn Would $d_1\to\infty$ be affected when $S=K$ , $S<K$ or $S>K$?

Comment: It does not matter. It suffices $\tau$ to be positive, as $d_1=\frac{\alpha}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}+\frac12{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}$. Obviously, the sign of $\alpha$ plays no role for $\sigma\to+\infty$.

Comment: @Idonknow: taking the limit as $\sigma\to\infty$ in the formula for $d_1$ should answer that.